# Matisse in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-3.4, matisse

I have just installed Eclipse 3.4 and found out that there is not a plugin to create Swing applications yet. I also have found that there is a Matisse implementation in MyEclipse IDE, but I'd like to now whether there is such a Matisse plugin for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instatiations Swing Designer is the best in my opinion. We settled on it after trying may different Eclipse plugins.

Comment: I didn't know it. Thank you very much for the recomendation. I'll try it.

Comment: Instatiations Swing Designer is now [Google WindowBuilder Pro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-wbpro)

Answer (score 2):

there isnt one for free. myeclipse is the only way to run matisse inside eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not a true answer to your question, you may as well look at alternative solutions in terms of layout management: Matisse and GroupLayout are neither the only way, nor the best one, to define your GUI forms.

I would suggest you take a look at:

- MigLayout (very powerful and quite
  simple)
- and DesignGridLayout (quite powerful
  and very simple)

Both are open source and have a friendly license (not GPL).
A quick search on Google will give you the links immediately.

Disclaimer: I am one of DesignGridLayout both project owners, but I point you to it because I'm convinced it provides a better way to define Swing layouts.

Comment: No problem, I'll check it. I mentioned Matisse because it's the best design I've knew so far, but I'm open to alternatives, as long as I can still work in eclipse. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick Google search and found that you could use Netbeans Matisse and Eclipse in parallel:

[NetBeans Wiki: UsingNetbeansMatisseAndEclipseInParallel](http://wiki.netbeans.org/UsingNetbeansMatisseAndEclipseInParallel)

It seems to basically involve building the Swing GUI in Netbeans and doing the other coding tasks from within Eclipse.

Comment: Yeah, I have being doing this. But this is not much practical, unfortunately. I'll read the article you recommended.